# Is there a way to start an activity email with Live Data with ViewModel?

Tags: email, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I understand that you cannot pass the activity nor the fragment to the view model as parameter  and in order to start events or update the UI by click  events it is preferable to use LiveData. However, I don't know how to start an email activity with LiveData. As far as I'm concerned you cannot start an activity on the class view model. This is the code that I have. (The lines in comments are just an examples, I know they won't work for this).

```
MainActivity.kt    
 
val obvserver = Observer<String> {studentEmail.setOnClickListener{ intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
                intent.type = "message/rfc822"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, selectedStudent.email)
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"))}}


studentEmail.setOnClickListener {
                //viewModel.
            }

ViewModel.kt
val studentEmail : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
MutableLiveData<String>()}
```

Comment: What causes the value of `studentEmail` to change? Are there multiple UI elements that must look different each time `studentEmail`'s value changes? Maybe LiveData isn't the most appropriate solution.

Comment: studentEmail stays intact. When the user click's on the student email, the email "activity" should appear. Or in UI terms, if the user wants to send an email he must click the student email. But I think you're right LiveData is not the best way.

Comment: I meant, how do you retrieve the value of `studentEmail`? If it is a time-consuming action, like checking a database or making a network request, LiveData or a Flow may be appropriate. If it is already known at the time the Activity is first opened, then it can probably just be a simple property.